# Print user inputs in 5 different statements

Tags: python, input

I`m new to Python.I need to get 2 values(e.g Black,White)as user inputs and print it 5 times like below example.

1.Colour for No 1 : Black
2.Colour for No 2 : White
3.Colour for No 3 : White
4.Colour for No 4 : Black
5.Colour for No 5 : White

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: Learn how to use for loop "https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_for_loops.asp"

Comment: Is it randomly or like a-b then b-a then a?

Answer (score 0):

Use *input()* to get user input.
Use a *for* loop to repeat 5 times.

```
for i in range(1,6):

    color = input()
    print(str(i)+". Color for number "+str(i)+": "+color)
```

Comment: The question is that user inputs 2 colours not 5

Comment: I understand the question differently: there are 2 different possible user inputs (Black and White) but the user does need to provide 5 times such input.

Comment: However, I agree that the question is not clear at all... The purpose of my answer is to point to useful Python tools that the OP will probably need (whatever he's trying to achieve).

Comment: Yes, you are right, the question is no clear at all and he or she has not shown the code tried.

Comment: Hi All,　Many thanks for your comments and advices.